# SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows 7 - Firewall issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-firewall

I'm totally stuck I hope someone can help.

I have a fresh copy of SQL Server 2008 Express installed on a Windows 7 pro machine with 2 instances created: Dev and Test.

I can connect to an instance via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) from the remote client only when the SQL Server Windows firewall is turned off, client firewall on.

I checked to make sure sql server firewall and client firewall have the same rules.

I've setup rules to allow TCP and UDP on local ports 1433 and 1434, remote ports-any, for inbound and outbound, on server and client pc.

I got so fed up that I enabled and allowed everything that was disabled. But still no worky.

I really have no idea what it could be so any help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution..

```
1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager

2. Select SQL Server Network Configuration

3. Select Protocols for [named instance]

4. Select IP Addresses tab

5. For each IP in the list, delete 0 from TCP Dynamic Ports and enter 7201 in TCP Port field below

6. One IP entry will have an IP address for the SQL Server - set this to Enabled and Active

7. Click Ok

8. Repeat steps 3 to 7 for another instance using port 7202

9. Open Firewall from Windows Control Panel

10. Advanced Settings

11. Add Inbound Rules based on Port:

    > Name 'My Instance SQL Server', TCP, port 7201
    > Name 'My Other Instance SQL Server', TCP, port 
    > 'Native SQL Server', TCP, port 1433
    > 'SQL Server', UDP, port 1434

12. Restart services

13. Ensure SQL Server Browser service is started
```